# Scroll automatic javascript

Tags: javascript, html, scroll

I have this code:

```
function scroll() {

  shouldScroll = chat.clientHeight === chat.scrollHeight;
  if (!shouldScroll) {
    scrollToBottom();
  }
}
function scrollToBottom() {
  chat.scrollTop = chat.scrollHeight;
}
scrollToBottom();
setInterval(scroll, 100);
```

In this code I have an automatically scroll but, When I want to see the whole conversation, he does not let me go up so I can read the conversations. It just keeps me down.

How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: You are calling `scroll()` every `1/10th` of a second, I imagine that `shouldScroll` is being evaluated as false each time, so it then calls `scrollToBottom()`. Which would reset the scoll to the bottom of the chat window. Have you tried debugging?

Comment: Yes but, the problem is that when I want to upload the scroll to see read the conversation automatically lowers me. It does not let me climb.

Answer (score 0):

Check if user has scrolled to another position using `scrollTop` or is near to the bottom by comparing to an offset:

```
var offset = 50; // if user is 50px far from bottom
var shouldScroll = false;
if (chat.scrollHeight - chat.scrollTop) < offset){
     shouldScroll = true;
}
```

Comment: This is only the logic to check if scroll is mandatory or not and you can use it besides of your own `scrollToBottom` function which seems to work fine. I do not suggest using `setInterval` but use it as soon as you update the chat content so you have to edit your codes (perhaps it is an ajax call or socket) and call the total code on chat updates. @IsaacAlejandro